# Magento - buy 1 product get another free

Tags: php, magento, promotions

I have two categories, I am trying to make some thing like if some one buys a product from one category, customer will have a option to choose a free product from another category(like a gift).

I found some thing similar to this in admin -

```
Promotions -> shopping cart price rule
```

You can create a rule that buy X qty of one product and get Y quantity of same product free. How can I make it - get X qty of product and get Y qty of another product free. Is this feature available in magento feature or do I have to implement this. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest [Special Promotions Pro](http://me.trexuna.com/r.php?r=special-promotions-pro) from Amasty because Magento default features for promotions is limited. It has all the features you need.

Answer (score 1):

you can check the below links for this purpose

http://www.webguys.de/magento/turchen-21-kostenlose-produkte-uber-warenkorb-preisregeln/

http://blog.goods-pro.com/1733/magento-extension-buy-x-selection-of-products-get-another-y-selection-for-free/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-setup-buy-x-get-y-free

Comment: Its giving me two options to create rule - 1.) conditions tab : Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met -- 2.) actions tab : Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions.How can i relate two category products- that buy category-X product and get one category-Y product free. I am only able to create a rule - buy category-X and get free product from same category (X).

Comment: I have added new links in my answer you can go through with them